# Examples of interior and limit point

Tags: general-topology

this may be rather an ignorant question but I am looking for reasoning's and examples of these types of examples:

$A = [0,1)$ then $(\overline{A}^{c}) = (-\infty,0)\bigcup(1,\infty)$ where $\overline{A}$ is simply the closure of $A$.

If anyone can find some examples or point me where I can turn to with examples and reasoning's for them I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the standard topology on $\Bbb{R}$, then any $x \in [0,1]$ is a limit point of $[0,1)$. The *boundary* points of $[0,1)$ are simply $\{0,1\}$. The interior of $[0,1)$ would be $(0,1)$ since it is the "largest" open set that you can fit inside $[0,1)$. This might not be the help you are looking for, but the  best way to understand is to spend some time with the definitions until things click.

Once again, this all assumes the standard topology on $\Bbb{R}$. The next thing you should do is try analyzing $[0,1)$ under a few different topologies. The lower limit topology, the finite complement topology, the discrete topology, etc.